# Do dynamic linked libraries(.dll,.so etc) have an entry point?

Tags: dll, shared-libraries, dynamic-linking, entry-point

Today I was in a discussion involving that libraries dont have an entry point.Generally the executable loads the libraries and the entry point is the main in the executable itself.

**Are there execeptions wherein the libraries themselves can have an entry point ??**

**Update:**

@sgr91 explained that DllMain is the entry point in Windows! What about linux ? Or is it just a feature of Windows ?

Comment: The entry point in DLL is optional. The function `DllMain` is the entry point of the DLL. If you want to do some initial work on DLL load, you can create the function, else you can skip it.

Comment: @sgar91 Can u elaborate more on what does "initial work on dll load" mean ? It would be helpful for me to understand :)

Comment: e.g you want to call a specific function when a DLL is loaded, you can call the function in DLLMain. Although it is highly discouraged to call an external function in DllMain.

Comment: Sorry I don't have much knowledge of Linux.

Comment: @sgar91 on Linux, there are _init and _fini sections, pointing to functions to run on load/unload. Roughly the same functionality as `DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH`/`DLL_PROCESS_DETACH` for `DllMain`.

Comment: @sgarizvi  Any clue for QNX (entry and exit points in dynamic link library)?

Comment: @AntonKovalenko Any clues for QNX platform?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, dynamic libraries do have entry-points.
It may be named differently (may or may not be exposed for usage), based on [compiler](https://wiki.apache.org/stdcxx/C++0xCompilerSupport) and OS.

**For Linux:**

```cc
void __attribute__ ((constructor)) my_init(void);

void __attribute__ ((destructor)) my_fini(void);
```

The `_init` and `_fini` sections are now obsolete.

Read [more](http://www.faqs.org/docs/Linux-HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO.html#INIT-AND-CLEANUP)

Comment: @yugr This is unrelated.

Comment: @JohanBoulé You mean suggesting to use standard language mechanisms instead of custom compiler extensions is unrelated?

Comment: @yugr You seemed to be confusing these two unrelated concepts. Library entry points are not standardised, so you have to use nonstandard definitions. When you dynamically load or unload a library, these functions are called (a bit like the main entry point of a program). Where do objects and their ctors/dtors fit into this picture? They don't. Show me some equivalent technic with static objects if you think you can obtain the same result.

Comment: @JohanBoulé "Where do objects and their ctors/dtors fit into this picture" - by allowing one to write portable (de)initializers without resorting to compiler extensions...

Comment: @yugr Are you implying, without being explicit at all, that static objects of a library are destroyed/freed (and, *IF* C++ is used, their dtor called), when we call dlclose/FreeLibrary to unload it ? I might buy your argument about static initialisation talking place before dlopen/LoadLibrary returns, but what about unloading?

Comment: @JohanBoulé They definitely are on Linux but I read they are not called in DLLs. This indeed making my comment above incorrect.

Comment: @yugr Well, that actually makes your comment relevant on linux at least :) You've taught something new to me.